# Como posso acessar um componente e fazê-lo com que apareça unicamente em uma janela Electron + Quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, javascript-eventos, electron, quasar

Eu gostaria de que o componente fosse exibido exatamente em uma janela única, mas não sei como fazer isso precisamente, o que consegui fazer foi apenas uma pequena base de um todo, até agora:

```
ipcMain.on('open-chat-window', (event) => {
  const janelasChat = []
  const chatWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
    width: 750,
    height: 650,
    useContentSize: true,
    autoHideMenuBar: true,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: process.env.QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION,
        nodeIntegrationInWorker: process.env.QUASAR_NODE_INTEGRATION
    },   
    backgroundColor: "#1d1d1d"
  })

  chatWindow.loadURL()

  janelasChat.push(chatWindow)
  event.reply('Janela de Chat Aberta')
})
```

Meu objetivo é fazer com que o usuário pressione um botão em um componente da janela principal e que o sistema responda criando uma nova janela, esta é a parte do código que invoco a criação desta janela. Mas como você pode ver, eu preciso inserir uma url no *loadURL()* e o que o ***Quasar*** me oferece é a variável vinda dele onde posso usar os componentes/pages/layouts dentro do projeto, chamada de:

```
process.env.APP_URL
```

Mas ao chamar esta variável dentro do *loadURL()*, ele irá renderizar todos os componentes, páginas e layouts dos quais trabalhei de forma sistemática, o que vai contra ao meu objetivo, apenas quero renderizar um componente dentro desta nova tela.

```
methods: {
    async openChatWindow () {
        if (this.$q.platform.is.electron) {
            const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
            ipcRenderer.send('open-chat-window')
        }
    }
}
```

Este é o método do qual quando invocado dentro do componente na Janela Principal, abre uma nova Janela, porém, como está sem a url, retorna-me um erro. Como posso proceder com a melhor solução para isto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É necessário passar na URL no processo do Electron sobre a mesma variável que o Quasar dispõe uma concatenação com a rota que irá passar. `loadURL(process.env.APP_URL + "#/URL")`